# How to create a full screen material-ui grid?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a layout similar to most editors/IDEs using material-ui and react, using material-ui Grid for the layout.
I have a top bar, a bottom bar, side panels on both sides and a center area. My question is: how to make this grid occupy the entire screen?

The way it is now, it only grows as far as the inner elements min-heights. I want both side panels to fill the screen vertically.

Here is a simple example with exactly the same layout I'm trying to implement: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-0pl9e

What I'm trying to do is to make the grid occupy the entire screen by expanding only the middle container.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a code snippet or codesandbox link, which shows what you've tried and what's not working. Look at how to create a [mcve].

Comment: look at the justify and alignContent properties

Comment: Thanks @MaazSyedAdeeb , I just added a codesandbox example

Comment: @dwjohnston The properties wont change the grid size.

Answer (score 6):

After a little research, I was able to achieve the expected behavior (the IDE-like layout) using viewport units and the css 'calc' function.

I used two material-ui Grids, namely 'mainGrid', with direction='row' (default) and a 'middleGrid', with direction='column'. 
The mainGrid style:

```
mainGrid: {
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100vh',
    spacing: 0,
    justify: 'space-around'
  }
```

And the middleGrid:

```
middleGrid: {
    height: `calc(100vh - ${uiDefault.APPBAR_HEIGHT})`,
    spacing: 0,
    direction: 'column'
  }
```

APPBAR_HEIGHT is a constant defining the fixed height of my top navigation bar. Using this scheme, its easy to get the proper, full screen layout. Results are saved in the same codesandbox shared in the question: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-0pl9e

Comment: Awesome, best answer, worked perrfectly for me. This saved my entire week :)

Comment: Good answer but their is a vertical gap between the middle two grids and the top.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Container 
      style={{
        border: "solid",
        minWidth: "100%",
        height: "100vh",
      }}
    > 
<Content/>
</Container>
```

border: "solid", (for visual purposes you can delete this)
you can use `<Grid>` insted

Comment: I have a grid inside a container and when I set `spacing` value on grid the page gets margin-bottom, but with `border:"solid"` it fills 100vh. why is that?

Answer (score -6):

```
<Grid classes={{root: {width: '100%'}}}>
    Grid content
</Grid>
```

Comment: I can't see that this would be required - block elements are full width by default.